# TypeScript: Using a plain JavaScript lib in web project, with custom typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a website project that uses TypeScript and Webpack. Now I need to use an external proprietary JavaScript library in this project. This is my project structure:

```
├── dist
│   ├── foo.js
│   ├── main.js
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── foo.d.ts
│   └── index.ts
├── webpack.config.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

File `dist/main.js` is generated by Webpack that uses `ts-loader` to compile the entry TypeScript file `src/index.ts`. Both `foo.js` and `main.js` are referenced in the `dist/index.html` file, using html script tag:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

The `dist/foo.js` library is a plain old JavaScript file, it is not an ES6 module, it just contains a bunch of classes.

I have created the `foo.d.ts` file with typings to assist TypeScript in type-checking the use of the classes defined in `foo.js`:

```
// src/foo.d.ts
export declare class MyClass {
  constructor(message: string);
}
```

But I have trouble registering it properly so that both TypeScript and Webpack deal with this setup properly. The problem lies in how TypeScript loads the type declarations file. If I refer to it with relative path, TypeScript can see and use it, but Webpack complains that it cannot resolve it:

This `index.ts` compiles, but Webpack gives error:

```
import { MyClass } from './foo';
const c = new MyClass('Hello, world!');
```

Webpack error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './foo' in '/path-to/src'`

The reason for Webpack failure apparently is that it is looking for the `foo` code and fails to find it, as the compiled JavaScript contains `require("./foo")`.

So I need to replace this line

```
import { MyClass } from './foo';
```

with something that tells TypeScript not to include this `require()` call in the compiled code. I think this problem is described in [this ts-loader discussion](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/639), but I am not sure what's the final verdict there. If I import like this

```
import { MyClass } from 'foo';
```

the TypeScript compiler gives error `Cannot find module 'foo' or its corresponding type declarations.`. Apparently something has to be specified in `tsconfig.json` for TypeScript to know where to look for the type declarations. But adding `"include": ["src/**/*"]` doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're lying about how you're *really* getting it (well, not really, you just don't know how to spell "this exists in the global scope" in your `.d.ts` file).

At runtime you're just relying on `MyClass` to exist somewhere up your scope chain, so you need to tell TypeScript that the environment you're working in is that kind of environment.  The way you do that is with an ambient module declaration that [modifies the global scope's type definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) - which is very similar to your definition except you don't use the `export` keyword:

```js
// src/foo.d.ts
// Note the lack of `export` here
declare class MyClass {
  constructor(message: string);
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using `window.MyClass`, then you use [a `global` declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html):

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    MyClass: MyClass
  }
}

declare class MyClass {
  myMethod(): void
}
```

Then, in your code, you can just `new MyClass("Hello world")` and TypeScript will have your back.

Comment: From the TS page on global .d.ts, I confirm that's the case with my library. But I wouldn't mind if I had to do `import {MyClass} from 'foo'`, that would leave me with less polluted global scope. The problem with your suggestion (of not having import at all) that tsc doesn't load the type definitions. I just get `Cannot find name 'MyClass'` error. How do I point TS to the d.ts file, or should it be specifically named/placed?

Comment: I think you need to configure `typeRoots` as well, or `baseUrl` + `include`.  See https://elfi-y.medium.com/typescript-ambient-module-8816c9e5d426